# xtaskcreate-getting error

Tags: freertos

Hello I am working on EZ430-RF2560T target board attached to debugging interface (attached to USB of PC) for the Tux Racer game application (MSP430BT5190 target board ). I am working on the accelerometer application code. After the bluetooth is turned On it gives the message "unable to create task " for the function
          xTaskCreate((pdTASK_CODE) user_task_routine,
                    (const signed portCHAR *)USER_TASK_NAME,
                    USER_TASK_STACK_SIZE, (unsigned portLONG *)NULL,
                    (unsigned portBASE_TYPE)USER_TASK_PRIORITY,
                    (xTaskHandle *) NULL);

Please let me know what could be done.........
              Thankyou
                                     Ashwin

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without more info or code. Looks like the task create line is straight from some dummy documentation or sample. Have you defined all the relevant parts such as USER_TASK_NAME, USER_TASK_STACK_SIZE, USER_TASK_PRIORITY, and especially the function user_task_routine?

Were there any compiler errors in this module?

The name "user task" sounds rather generic, maybe you might consider a descriptive name :)

Are other demo tasks running on the board? You might compare your task to them and see how they are started.

Could you simply be running out of memory? Try disabling some of the other tasks and starting only your task.

There is also a support community at freertos.org that tends to provide helpful responses.